# Server-side Rendering with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies if this has the feeling of a question asked many times before, but every guide to this problem tends to over-engineer a solution without ever really explaining the methodology behind it.

I have a React front-end (with react-router but no other techs) that, currently, is built (via create-react-app's build task) and then served by Node. No problem, all works fine.

To turn this into a SSR'd solution, is it as simple as, within the route definition:

```
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
const MyRootComponent = require('path/to/component');
return response.send(ReactDOM.renderToString(MyRootComponent));
```

Assume that MyRootComponent is the React component containing my routes.

Thanks for any and all pointers!

Comment: Have you tried it already? Did it not work? To me it looks like it would work to render at least a static HTML representation of your component, which then obviously you might need to re-mount on the front end for interactivity...

Comment: You need to add doctype, scripts, styles, serialize initial state, handle initial data loading (if your components need some data from say database). Summing all this things up will result in "over-engineered" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

There are few caveats:
i.e., the lifecycle of the components is not the same; on the server you can't have componentWillReceiveProps